# An idea about cooperation between development engineers and test engineers

Tags: java, testing, qa

Suppose we want to develop a small module (time needed: two weeks of one developer). Then what about this new (maybe?) pipeline:

1. The test engineer starts working:

   - Think about all cases (including many edge cases) that we need to test.
   - Write them down as code using an automated testing framework.
   - At this stage, the testing code all fails, because the business code does not yet exist.
2. After the test engineer finishes, the developer starts:

   - Develop business code. During development, run the test code above. (Now the dev does not need to use things like PostMan to manually test his code over and over again.)
   - The testing code may contain bugs, and the developer should fix it. (Since the testing code is mostly straightforward, it should be not challenging to fix)
   - When all test code passes, the code is almost done.
3. The test engineer checks that the modification of tests does not throw away things he wants to test.
4. Done.

P.S. We are talking about E2E tests here, not unit tests. IMHO unit tests should be done by programmers (is it correct?).

P.S. We are small teams, so maybe not able to use the methodology in big companies.

Is this methodology acceptable/wonderful/terrible/awful?

Comment: I challenge you to have testers write all the E2E tests in advance.

Comment: @Euphoric Good question! I will think about it twice. Thanks!

Comment: If it is true that the task only needs two weeks of developer time, you can iterate this. However, when picking the requirements and when writing the tests, there are no guarantees that it will actually take two weeks to complete.

Comment: Instead of building such a castle in the air, why not try it out (you can do this alone) to see where the problems with this approach are? Start with something like Tetris (which should perfectly fit into your time frame if you are an experienced dev). Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a non-iterative version of *Acceptance Test Driven Development*. Like all non-iterative processes, it suffers from the fact that it assumes it can perfectly predict the future, that the client never changes their mind, that requirements, markets, environments, and circumstances never change.

ATDD works in an iterative fashion: the test engineer writes *one test* together with the business analyst and/or client. The developer gets the test to pass. The project is built and delivered to the client, who can already play around with the product. While playing around, the client will inevitably discover that they missed some requirement or misjudged the impact of some decision they made.

Based on the feedback from the client, the test engineer then writes a second test together with the business analyst and/or client. And so on …

Note also that typically in ATDD, the test engineer and developer are the same person, although they don't have to be. (If they aren't, you could do some overlap in the phases, e.g. have the test engineer create the second test while the developer still implements the first requirement.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Now I know the term and more sophicicated pipeline!

Answer (score 0):

In the frames of TDD/BDD the question seems not properly defined.
The testing is planned and started implementing upon an interface part is defined. Normally, an  Agile development team must provide unit-suit integration tests to prove that the created classes satisfy the user stories, and meet non-functional requirements such as performance, GC limitations, and resource consumption. Furthermore, testing can contain related metrics as a subject for the assertion, which is proof of the right of the class to live. So, the tester should understand the tested objects no less than its developer. Pair programming, when one engineer writes implementation and the second writes tests (with rotation), and they have planned all the work together is more reasonable
Any module should contain tests, which test each one of the requirements (functional and not functional), Because a module represents a part of business logic, it is a good practice when acceptance constraints are defined with the participation of the project architect, or business analysts and they should correspond to real conditions, where the class will work in.
From another hand, testing is an excellent reason to review a written code yet once and understand what is done, and what can be improved still.
In this way, a test engineer and a development engineer have almost the same role in the project: both of them should understand what is going to be done,  and the whole cycle. Also, this way helps to build a shared vision of engineering and problems. Undoubtedly, testing must be planned and started no later, than implementation has been started.
Another way is to implement the planned interfaces and features and delegate testing to a test engineer. And even in this case, the test plan and its implementation must be elaborated a collegiate way within the same forum. But the second way has a less cohesive collaboration level and I do not believe that it could be effective more than the first one.
Finally, XP or Pair Programming has proved the first method of programming as effective, where separation engineer-test engineer is very conditional and temporal: the roles are rotated usually. So the best collaboration is the collaboration of engineers of Pair Programming with rotated roles.